# C++ - Using typename and template error

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I built a doubly linkedlist using a template class, The class i built contain innter public class **linkedListNode** which contain private field **next** and **previous**.
For encapsulation issues i wanted to define a method that return the next node

```
template <class T>
MyLinkedList<T>::MyLinkedListNode* MyLinkedList<T>::MyLinkedListNode::getNext()
{
    return this -> next;
}
```

but it is a compilation error.
I also tryed to use typename and it also a compilation error

The compliation error is :

> need ‘typename’ before ‘MyLinkedList::MyLinkedListNode’ because
>   ‘MyLinkedList’ is a dependent scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `MyLinkedList<T>` is instantiated, there's a chance that it could be a value instead of a type. The `typename` keyword is required to let the compiler know that it is a type. For a dependent name, the compiler does not make any assumptions. It is up to the programmer to sprinkle `typename` and `template` keywords in the correct locations. Lucky for you, it's right in the error message. It can't get any easier than that.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler tells you:

> need ‘typename’ before ‘MyLinkedList::MyLinkedListNode’ because ‘MyLinkedList’ is a dependent scope

You should use `typename` because `MyLinkedList<T>::MyLinkedListNode*` is a dependent name (it depends on the template argument `T`). You can fix your code with:

```
template <class T>
typename MyLinkedList<T>::MyLinkedListNode* MyLinkedList<T>::MyLinkedListNode::getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}
```

As [you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ab5bc337a520713) it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

your compiler tell you the solution:

```
template <class T>
typename MyLinkedList<T>::MyLinkedListNode* MyLinkedList<T>::MyLinkedListNode::getNext()
{
    return this -> next;
}
```